# Send data peer-to-peer between Nexus S and NFC shield

Tags: cordova, tags, arduino, nfc, nexus-s

I use [p2pdemo](https://github.com/don/phonegap-p2p) from [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap) and share tag.

I connect the [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) + [NFC shield](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/NFC_Shield) and run the board with [PtoPtarget.pde](http://seeedstudio.com/wiki/NFC_Shield#Demo_2%3a_PtoPInitiator.pde_and_PtoPTarget.pde).

I don't know how the two devices can transmit data together. Is there source code to run the application? Or how do get it?

I'm not sure when I run the p2pdemo application and what data is send from the phone? And does the board understand the type of data that the phone sends?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a NFC Shield and Nexus S as peers using the p2pdemo that you have specified. The p2pdemo requires two Mobile phones.